# Filtering python string through external program

Tags: python

What's the cleanest way of filtering a Python string through an external program? In particular, how do you write the following function?

```
def filter_through(s, ext_cmd):
  # Filters string s through ext_cmd, and returns the result.

# Example usage:
#   filter a multiline string through tac to reverse the order.
filter_through("one\ntwo\nthree\n", "tac")
#   => returns "three\ntwo\none\n"
```

Note: the example is only that - I realize there are much better ways of reversing lines in python.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) module.

In your case, you could use something like

```
import subprocess
proc=subprocess.Popen(['tac','-'], shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                      stdout=subprocess.PIPE, )
output,_=proc.communicate('one\ntwo\nthree\n')
print output
```

Note that the command sent is `tac -` so that `tac` expects input from stdin.
We send to stdin by calling the `communicate` method. `communicate` returns a 2-tuple: the output from stdout, and stderr.